# How to delete a particular resource from resource group in Azure using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-group

I am using azure.mgmt.resource for deleting a resource group from azure but can i delete a particular resource without deleting a resource group?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use the specific client of the resource type as explained in another answer, you can use one of the two generic delete in the `azure-mgmt-resource` package and the ResourceManagementClient:

- [delete_by_id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2017_05_10.operations.resourcesoperations?view=azure-python#azure_mgmt_resource_resources_v2017_05_10_operations_ResourcesOperations_delete_by_id)
- [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2017_05_10.operations.resourcesoperations?view=azure-python#azure_mgmt_resource_resources_v2017_05_10_operations_ResourcesOperations_delete)

Note that the ApiVersion asked is the one from the resource you want to delete. Please look at the RestAPI documentation to get an ApiVersion depending of the resource type you want to delete. For instance, you can get the ApiVersion of Storage in that page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storagerp/

Comment: Can you please tell how to use this? @laurent

Comment: I am using it like following :-

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=clientid,secret=clientsecret,tenant=tenantid)
                client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)
                delete_async_operation = client.resourceoperations.delete_by_id(resource_id,api)
                delete_async_operation.wait()


But getting error:-

'ResourceManagementClient' object has no attribute 'resourceoperations'

Comment: Start with this sample to understand on to use a ResourceManagementClient https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups

Answer (score 0):

For example, If you are deleting a VM in a resource group

```html
Delete VM
        print('\nDelete VM')
        async_vm_delete = compute_client.virtual_machines.delete(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME)
        async_vm_delete.wait()
```

[Azure-Samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups/blob/master/example.py)

[Manage Azure resources and resource groups with Python:](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups/)

Additional information: [Click here](http://www.codeisahighway.com/effective-ways-to-delete-resources-in-a-resource-group-on-azure/)

Comment: I don`t want to delete a specific resource . I want to delete any resource.Is that possible??